# Как получить данные из словаря KeyValuePair в другом классе в разных namespace

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, .net

Ребят, добрый вечер. Помогите решить проблему. Суть: есть **class 1** в **namespace 1**, где есть коллекция со словарем KeyValuePair:

```
        public static void fileStreaming(string fileName)
    {
        ICollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>> FileStreamsLines = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        StreamReader fileReader = null;
        try
        {
            fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
            string filestream;
            filestream = fileReader.ReadLine();
            fileReader.Close();
            FileStreamsLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fileName, filestream));
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not file in IsolatedStorage");
        }
    }
```

и есть другой **namespace 2** с **class 2**, где:

```
        public IndexPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Внимание вопрос: как получить данные из словаря, находящемся в **namespace 1**, для работы с ними в **namespace 2**?

Answer (score 3):

Уж простите мою беспросветную дремучесть, но я правильно понимаю, что вы либо путаете класс и метод (вы привели примеры двух методов, а не классов), либо привели неверный код? Так или иначе, из вашего кода следует, что вы хотите использовать локальную переменную FileStreamsLines метода fileStreaming в методе IndexPage.  Вне зависимости от того, принадлежат ли эти методы одному классу, или нескольким, использование локальных переменных одного невозможно (и в общем-то бессмысленно) в другом. У данной переменной область видимости ограничена пределами метода.

З.Ы. а в чем сакральный смысл использования ICollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>>? Почему не использовать интуитивно более понятный Dictionary<string,string>, или, что лучше, IDictionary<string,string>?

Comment: Насчет методов и классов: собственно есть первый класс в одном namespace, в котором находится метод fileStreaming, и есть второй класс в уже другом namespace, где находится метод IndexPage. Вот я и хочу из первого класса вытащить данные во второй класс, но слабо представляю, как это сделать. Как-то так.

Что касается ICollection и IDictionary - в разработке я новичок, поэтому да, скорее всего лучше делать IDictionary<string,string>. Так что, каким-то способом (пусть даже и костыльным) вытащить не удастся?

Comment: FileStreamsLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fileName, filestream));

Отсюда: я хочу работать с fileName и filestream в методе IndexPage.

Comment: >Так что, каким-то способом (пусть даже и костыльным) вытащить не удастся?

стесняюсь спросить, а в чем проблема-то? Как вы пробовали "вытащить"? Я просто не вижу, как вы это делали

Comment: @DreamChild: исходя из вопроса, никак. И мне кажется, ТС должен бы сначала почитать какую-нибудь базовую книжку по программированию, где расписано, чем отличаются автоматические переменные внутри процедуры от полей структуры данных.